# How to get the server-name?

Tags: server

When starting a server it's possible to set a name for the server (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html). These names are to be useful for connecting emacsclients to those servers, however it would be nice to switch some behavior in my config based on the server name(my initial thoughts are changing the theme).

I've dug around on google and the best way seems to be setting an env var and then reading that back in the configuration (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc13). I can't seem to find a way to get this information from within emacs without setting the env var, and I'd rather not have to run a separate wrapper just to know what server is running. How would I go about finding this information programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

It appears `daemonp` will return the name of the server. I ended up with code that looks something like

```
(cond
 ((string= "org" (daemonp))
  (load-theme 'solarized-light)
 )
 (t
  (load-theme 'solarized-dark)
 )
)
```

Comment: `daemonp` is a *predicate*, it either returns `t` or `nil`.

Comment: I'm on 24.4.1 and `daemonp` is returning the name of the server. I updated the sample to use `string=` because `daemonp` will return `nil` if emacs isn't running a server.

Comment: According to the sources, `daemonp` can do both.  For the server it can return either its name or `nil`, for the client it can be both `t` and `nil`.  This is pretty bonkers considering there's the `server-name` variable, yet no exposed `daemon-name` variable.

Comment: The builtin documentation also states that daemonp has a dual behavior 
`   daemonp is a built-in function in `C source code'. 
   (daemonp)
    
    Return non-nil if the current emacs process is a daemon.
    If the daemon was given a name argument, return that name.`

I suggest you to accept your own answer

Answer (score 4):

In a client instance the variable `server-name` is bound and contains the server name.

```
(and (boundp 'server-name) server-name)
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `server-name`, but it is only set in the client and so isn't available during initialization.